# customizing git diff output format (own function name for my files in chunk header)

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm using git 2.14.1 on Linux/x86-64/Debian/Sid. I don't have any shell environment variable with `GIT`. I've read the [git diff format](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format) page. Here is output of `git config -l`, for my current project (on github) [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) :

```
user.name=Basile Starynkevitch
user.email=basile@starynkevitch.net
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:bstarynk/bismon.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

When I do a `git diff` on some C file like `main_BM.c` I'm getting an output like

```
diff --git a/main_BM.c b/main_BM.c
index 3639a52..9c43d9e 100644
--- a/main_BM.c
+++ b/main_BM.c
@@ -371,6 +371,7 @@ rungui_BM (void)
     }
   if (gui_command_log_file_BM)
     {
+      /// the current time
       {
         time_t nowtim = time (NULL);
         struct tm nowtm = { };
```

Notice the chunk header line `@@ -371,6 +371,7 @@ rungui_BM (void)`; it shows a function name (e.g. `rungui_BM`), and I don't understand why and how (but I like that).

I have also several `.bismon` textual files (machine generated, but versioned under git, and could be considered as some simplistic domain specific language). For example my [`store2.bismon`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/store2.bismon) contains stuff like

```
!(_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK |=basiclo_temporary_module|
!~ name (~ basiclo_temporary_module
~)
!@ 1504862208.05
!$_0LK4TzFd6u1_0JFUsrQ4odG |=class|
!: _01h86SAfOfg_1q2oMegGRwW |=comment|
 "class of temporary modules containing only functions for closures"
!~ class (~ |supercl plain_temporary_module:| _1oEp0eAAyFN_4lsobepyr1T
~)

!)_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK
```

<sup>(My `store*.bismon` have their own format -that I defined and could slightly change if convenient- and basically represents a dump of the persistent memory heap of some interpreter)</sup>

From the point of view of `git diff`, I would like that any line similar to
`!(_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK |=basiclo_temporary_module|`
(that is any line starting with `!(_` followed by 11 alphanumerical characters followed by `_` followed by 11 alphanumerical characters) be considered by `git diff` as a function start and displayed by `git diff` in the `@@`  chunk header.

Currently `git diff store2.bismon` don't give nice chunk headers like I would want them:

```
diff --git a/store2.bismon b/store2.bismon
index edbb2f7..3847b6b 100644
--- a/store2.bismon
+++ b/store2.bismon
@@ -6,7 +6,13 @@
 !(_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK |=basiclo_temporary_module|
 !~ name (~ basiclo_temporary_module
 ~)
-!@ 1504861742.79
+!@ 1504862208.05
+!$_0LK4TzFd6u1_0JFUsrQ4odG |=class|
+!: _01h86SAfOfg_1q2oMegGRwW |=comment|
+ "class of temporary modules containing only functions for closures"
+!~ class (~ |supercl plain_temporary_module:| _1oEp0eAAyFN_4lsobepyr1T
+~)
+
 !)_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK
```

I would like the chunk header line `@@ -6,7 +6,13 @@` to be something like:

```
 @@ -6,7 +6,13 @@ !(_0277f6mOd9j_0tVZSXnTzUK |=basiclo_temporary_module|
```

Maybe I need to have some `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` set to some script. But how is that thing invoked and by what subpart of `git`?

If possible, I would like the colors used by `git diff` to stay the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to [define a custom hunk-header](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header):

```
echo '*.bismon diff=bismon' > .gitattributes
git config diff.bismon.xfuncname '^!\(_.*$'
```

You can adapt the regexp for more accuracy